# Track folder/file changes in PHP only

Tags: php, mysql, file

**First some background information:**

I'm trying to write an application that uses only PHP, whereby any changes to the server are rejected. Exec() and the likes are turned off for safety sake. The server is running on PHP 5.3 and MySQL (via PDO) is the database used.

The application now needs to keep track of a couple of files, and save the plain text of some file formats (pdf, doc, docx, xlsx, txt) to the database for indexing and searching. These files are on a network drive, but are accessible by the server via the readdir()-function. Each file roughly takes 10-15 seconds to access.
I can go over each file in a directory (and sub directories recursively), calculate the md5 hash of that file, save it to the database and then use this database to search thorough via full-text search. The database used at the moment looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MY_FILE` (
  `FILE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FILE_NAME` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `FILE_CHECKSUM` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FILE_MODIFIED` datetime NOT NULL,
  `FILE_TEXT` text,
  `FILE_FULLPATH` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FILE_BYTESIZE` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

FILE_TEXT is null when the file doesn't have plaintext (like images), and therefor will not be searched. In the future, these rows will go away. All this information is already being indexed at the moment, and therefor accessible if needed in the answer.

**Then the problem:**

The problem I walked into today is that I know of no way to keep track of whether a file is moved, renamed or deleted, in a PHP-only manner. The indexing (Reading, checking if the path of a file in the database is existing, and if so updating it if it has a different checksum) of files as-is already takes more than a couple of minutes, because the files take roughly 10-15 seconds to load (PER FILE!), so using the same method for checking each row in the database to make sure the file is still there is not going to happen. That will take days to complete, and by that time the files could have been moved/deleted/renamed again.

Comment: You could get the size of the directory, and check the previous size to the current size. If it's the same, assume no files have been moved/deleted/added. Unsure how you'd keep track of renaming. How often does renaming/deleting/moved files happen, roughly?

Comment: Depends from time to time. I haven't tested the code in production environment just yet, so I can't say for sure. But I would say about once every other week. So I might be exaggerating when saying the files could change in the meantime, but we can't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of a server as a layered environment, then you will come to the conclusion, that there's no really efficient way to achieve that in PHP, only.

One way might be the [File Alteration Monitor](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fam.php) package, which was bundled with PHP up to 5.0.5, now it is a PECL extension.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case. I couldn't think of any other way myself either. That's why I asked here. Making changes to the server is however really out of the question. So if it's not natively supported, it's not possible, which is a shame. It feels like I'm reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are recursing your directories you could build a hash array contents hashes. I think you will also need to place a text file in each directory to track directory renames. If a file is renamed *and* updated there will be no way to track it but you could track either update or renaming.

Generate a random hash for each "new" directory and place it in a hidden file in each directory. Generate a directory_hash.filename_hash and file contents_hash.

Example:

```
$dir_hash = md5(c:\dir1); //03b3b29430d1bf67ffe51263d270a94c
```

You may need make it more random in case a directory is deleted and another one is created with the same name

So place a hidden file 03b3b29430d1bf67ffe51263d270a94c in c:\dir1

c:\dir1\image.jpg

```
$filename_hash = md5(image.jpg); //0d5b1c4c7f720f698946c7f6ab08f687
$contents_hash = md5(file_get_contents(c:\dir1\image.jpg));
```

So building your hash array would be like so:

```
$hash_array[$dir_hash][$filename_hash] = $contents_hash;
```

You can reference this array while cycling through the directories or while cycling through the array. You will need to cycle through both to achieve your goals, the array for deleted files and directories, the directories for new files and directories.

Comment: I like your answer, however, upon further inspection, the webserver has no write-access to the fileserver, only read-access. The sole problem lies in the fileserver being so god-damn slow. Reading from a local drive is much, much faster